# treeview, parse through items

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below smart tree taken from [this](https://www.htmlelements.com/demos/tree/hierarchical-checkboxes/) link:

```
    <smart-tree smart-tree-default-height="10" id="treeCurie"  has-three-states selection-mode="checkBox">
    <smart-tree-items-group>IPV4
        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSEC
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>

        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSEC_QOS
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>

        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>

        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF_TNAT
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>

        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF_SNAT_ZBFW
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>
    </smart-tree-items-group>

    <smart-tree-items-group>MCAST
        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSEC_MCAST
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>

        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF_MCAST
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>
    </smart-tree-items-group>

    <smart-tree-items-group>IPV6
        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSECV6
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>

        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSECV6_QOSV6_DPI_FNF
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>
    </smart-tree-items-group>
</smart-tree>
```

Using javascript, I want to iterate through this tree and come up with this string:
`IPSEC-IMIX_1400,IPSEC_MCAST-IMIX` etc depending on what items are selected.

I tried to use the API `getselectedvalues` [here](https://www.htmlelements.com/demos/tree/hierarchical-checkboxes/#toc-getselectedvalues) but I am getting the value like this:

[image]

Please help me as I am new to this.